# VirtualBox Kernel not loaded

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and VirtualBox 5.1.8*

I would like to make create a few Virtual machines, but Virtual Box gives this error message when I start it:

> ```
> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>      available for the current kernel (4.4.0-45-generic) or it failed to
>      load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
>     sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
>
>     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```

And so I run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`. Output:

> ```
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
> vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find   out why.
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
> /sbin/vboxconfig
> as root.
> ```

Messages selected as Errors on `dmesg` :

> ```
>  [    0.849685] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.SDMA
>  [    0.849689] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.SDHC
>
>
>
> [    0.944531] EFI: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-74)
> [    0.944754] EFI: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-74)
> [    0.944982] EFI: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-74)
> ```

Comment: So-called "Secure boot"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable **secure boot** in BIOS. At least it worked for me

Comment: worked for me too, thx